# Ubuntu 22.04 USG hardening script breaks DNS resolution

Tags: dns, security

Since a few days, I noticed that running USG hardening tool on a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 server, breaks DNS resolution.
Running for example `dig google.com` throws out an error:

```
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached
```

I looked up almost every DNS setting in this server, and read several DNS troubleshoot tutorials, but haven't found a fix yet.
I also compared this server to another one running the same configuration (22.04 and hardened with USG module), and the only difference I've noticed so far is that in the output of `resolvectl` the line `Current DNS Server: 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:1` is missing:

```
Link 2 (eth0)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:1 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:2 185.12.64.1 185.12.64.2
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.